# Can I unlock login keyring with fprintd on my Thinkpad w500?

Tags: login, password, lenovo, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad W500 with fingerprint sensor.  I have installed the `fprintd` software and got it working with `fprintd-enroll`.

However, I thought when you signed in your fingerprint you are done but I am asked to enter my password with a box saying enter password to unlock your login keyring.

I was not expecting to have a to enter my password after installing the software which is working at sign on and `sudo` commands.

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 and I am a newbie with Linux.  Have I done something wrong or am I always going to have to enter the password like this after using finger to sign in?